# How to update the existing todo item in Rust language

Tags: rust

Currently building a CRUD system and want to replace the selected item with the new updated item value. Since I am a noob, still need to learn lot of things, so how can I fix this. Completely confused on how to fix that.

What the current problem is that I am not able to find the item name for example bob and replace that with a new item value.

```
let action = std::env::args().nth(1).expect("Please provide an action");
let item = std::env::args().nth(2).expect("Please provide an item");
let _getitem = std::env::args().nth(3).expect("Please provide an item");

struct Todo {
    map: HashMap<String, bool>,
}

if action == "edit" {
    match todo.edit(&item, &_getitem) {
        None => println!("'{}' is not present in the list", item),
        Some(_) => match todo.save() {
            Ok(_) => println!("todo saved"),
            Err(why) => println!("An error occurred: {}", why),
        },
    }
}

fn edit(&mut self, key: &String, value: &String) -> Option<()> {
    let elements = self.map.get_mut(key);
    elements.push(value.to_string());
}
```

Data structure of hashmap looks like:

```json
{"bob": true, "new": true }
```

Comment: What data structure is `elements` in `elements.push(value.to_string());` it looks like you are pushing as if it was a `Vec` if it is replace the value at `elements[0]` or if it is a `string` just assign the value

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do in your `edit` function, if you just want to remove the value from the hashmap you can just call `remove` on map: `map.remove(key)` then you can add the new item with `map.insert(key, value)`

Comment: Just ignore what is inside the function of edit, i am a noob when it comes to Rust, only thing I want to achieve is to replace the the value for example bob with new value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to `update` an existing record in a HashMap. One way to go about this is using `HashMap::entry` ([Rust Doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry)):

Once you select an entry you can modify it using the [Entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html). This allows you to chain updates and inserts, for example:

```rust
let mut map: HashMap<&'static str, usize> = HashMap::new();
map.insert("a", 1);
map
  .entry("a")
  .and_modify(|val| *val += 1);
```

In your case `edit` can look like this:

```rust
fn edit(&mut self, key: &String, value: bool) {
    self.map.entry(key)
      .and_modify(|val| *val = value);
}
```

Note that in your example the value of a HashMap must be `bool` but you are trying to update it to a string. You need to parse this first, e.g. using `from_str` ([Rust Doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html#tymethod.from_str)) or by using your own function:

```
fn to_bool(s: &str) -> Result<bool, ()> {
  if s == "x" {
     return Ok(true);
  }
  if s == "" {
     return Ok(false);
  }
  Err(())
}
```

Comment: I want to enter this in command line: cargo run -- edit bob newitem...but it nags about  the 'key' expected struct `std::string::String`, found `&std::string::String`